# Entry in Mac's /etc/hosts file causes Rails server error with no stacktrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipv6

I spent a good 40 minutes trying to understand why I was getting an error when accessing my Rails server. There was absolutely no error message or stack-trace which made it even harder to understand what was going on.

Turns out that I magically got the following line in my /etc/hosts file on my Macbook Pro:

```
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

`fe80::1%lo0` is the IPv6 version for `127.0.0.1` which apparently doesn't work nicely with Rails.

Is there an official workaround for this? For now I've just commented the entry out in /etc/hosts and it seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, `::1` is the IPv6 equivalent to the IPv4 `127.0.0.1`, and  `fe80::1` is a link-local address, not a loopback address.

Comment: That isn't a valid loopback address.
Your loopback should be listed as:
    ::1             localhost